# Why can't I publish the project?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, publish, umbraco7

So I'm trying to publish a project to a local folder, which normally works. But as soon as I get contents from another site to implement the new update into it, it fails. There are no errors what so ever, and in the suggested tmp-file, it says to check the output window. I am using Umbraco Version 7.15.5.

Thank you for your help in advance!

The error:

[image: error]

The tmp-file:

[image: temp-file]

The output-window:

[image: output-window]

The Error List:

[image: Errorlist]

Publish-Window:

[image: publishwindow]

Comment: Can you Rebuild` you solution.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath yes I can, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Great.. awesome.. :)

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath well yes, but actually no. I still can't publish, had to manually copy the files I needed.

Comment: are you getting same error?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath yes.

Comment: Can you delete content of this folder and re-Publish, and check if content appears
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I already did that, and it publishes everything until it gets to a specific file.

Comment: Hi @Gogo Dev,can you delete all the pubxml files from your properties folder and create a new publish profile? `Keep a backup before you delete.`

Comment: It's possible that you have a file included in your project that is actually missing.

Comment: @MarioLopez could be, but how do I find out?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath did that as well, didn't work.

Comment: Try this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidGardiner.ShowMissing2019

Comment: @GogoDev can you try making `Delete existing file` to false. I paste as answer as I cannot post screenshot here.

Comment: @MarioLopez well I've downloaded the missing files tool, and deleted or included every file that was shown as an error. Sadly it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make `Delete existing file` as False. Delete the files manually and check.

[image]

Comment: try to run Visual studio as Administrator

Comment: I always run vs as admin.